# SQL stuck with data structure in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot-table

I need to create a report based on absence from work, currently the data is stored in table with the following structure:

```
Date | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Name5
```

Each time an employee is off their employee ID is added into one of the columns next to the date they are off. I’m struggling to figure out a decent way of using the data as it is.

Ideally what I would like to achieve is reversing the way the data is so that the employee ID has the date’s they are off, not 5 columns  per each date if 5 people are off. For example:

```
EmpName | Date
JWC     | 22/03/2013
JWC     | 23/03/2013
```

Never had to do anything similar to this before so am a bit lost. Would a pivot help in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT 
    empl
    , dt
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT
            dt,
            id1,
            id2,
            id3
        FROM 
            data
) d
UNPIVOT
( 
    empl FOR epl IN ( id1, id2, id3 ) 
) u
ORDER BY 
    empl, 
    dt
```

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7e7c/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to over complicate this massively, simple did a few unions to collate them and put them into a different table. Might not be the best resolution but it works perfectly.